# Shell script kill command

Tags: python, shell, terminal, sh, os.system

- OS: Raspbian
- Python: 3.7.3

I am trying to run and kill my shell script through a Python script. The purpose is so that I can simply press "Run" in my py script, instead of having to go through the terminal every time. Here is my shell script (T.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Track command

cd /home/pi/rpi-deep-pantilt
. . /rpi-deep-pantilt-env/bin/activate
rpi-deep-pantilt track Raspi --edge-tpu
```

Here is my Py script:

```
import os
os.system('bash /home/pi/T.sh')
```

When I issue the command `rpi-deep-pantilt track Raspi --edge-tpu` in my terminal and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it kills the script, but it doesn't work when I use this Python script, and neither does pkill. The Python script stops, but the camera stays on and the tracking functionality is still operating. Is there any way I can incorporate some kill command that I can issue with a key interruption?

If there is a better way to go about this let me know. I'm very new to this as you can probably tell.

Comment: Does it work if you type `bash /home/pi/T.sh` in the console itself?

Comment: If you use `subprocess` library, you can kill the script process by python code. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html  If you combine this with `signal` library which provides features to catch keyboard interruption, I guess you can implement what you want.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Answer (score 0):

Python may create a new process for T.sh, so within your python code, try:

```
os.system("pkill T.sh")
```

Comment: I added this in right below: 'os.system('bash /home/pi/T.sh')'  but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Um, could you run your python script and once its ran. Kill it and run this: ps –aux and show me the output.